# Transferring database objects from one DB to another — Django / Postgres

Tags: database, django, merge

I have a dev site and a live site for my Django app. A lot of front end copy and other object details are stored in the DB. Conversely, a lot of client data is also stored in the DB. What's the most efficient way to get the dev site ready and then copying over the new copy and objects to the live server?

I guess the easiest is to keep the changeable dev site data up to date with the live site, then update the dev site, then do a data dump over to the live site. But what happens if/when someone updates the live site whilst this is happening? Their update will be overwritten.

Is there a Django app to allow me to 'check' entries in the admin list view, press 'copy' then somehow paste these into the new site?

Or what are the other patterns people use for this common scenario?

It's a bit like using GIT - having a master branch, then a branch for each live site iteration, then creating hot fixes on the live site, whilst still working on the dev site — the hotfix can be merged into the dev site. How do we merge the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get it correctly, please tell me if I'm wrong: so basically, you want to make changes on the (same) data both in production and in your dev instance ?

IMHO it is generally not a good solution for many reasons, one of those being this fragile need to merge you mentioned. To me, the best way to approach this would be in fact to keep the two environments as detached as possible (data-wise).

The part to avoid at all costs, IMHO, is this final dev->production merge. I can understand a little better the need to transfer in the other direction (from prod to dev). I can see two common cases here:

- You want the same data in dev. to try to reproduce a data-related bug. In that case, why not simply dumping the production database and load it on the dev. machine ? IMHO, this dev. database should be considered "wipeable" all the time.
- You have some "initial" data on the production site that is generic enough to be also needed in dev (something like Male/Female entries in a "Gender" table). In that case, you can imagine using [Fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

While thinking about you data flows and environments, you should probably also have a look at [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), data migration is a **very** useful tool.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I use South in all my projects - it's very useful indeed for data structure changes - rather than actual data changes. I think the way to go here would be to use fixtures for the "Display - copy" parts of the site - i.e. set up the DEV site as it should be - do any South migrations, then apply any Fixtures. The trick would be to make sure the Dev site "Display" data is up to date with the live site before doing the merge back.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a Django app to allow me to 'check' entries in the admin list view, press 'copy' then somehow paste these into the new site?

Not that I know off. But I think you could write such an app with a reasonable amount of effort. I would suggest the following:

- Use admin actions for the change list view. That way you could *publish* or *transfer* multiple objects from your development system to your live system. [See the documentation for further information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).
- Add another button to the *change view* of a single object. Maybe "Publish to Live site".
- Add yet another button to the *change view* that saves and publishes in one step, like "Save and publish to Live site".

To add buttons to the change form I would override the corresponding template:

http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html

Override the block 'submit_buttons_bottom' like

```
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <!-- your buttons here -->
{% endblock %}
```

Preferably you would write just one function that does the job of transfering the object from the dev to the live system. Use this function in all three use cases.

**But there is a catch!**

It could be fairly hard to *copy* one object from one Django instance to another. Especially so, if those objects have relationships with other objects, which in turn might have relationships with yet another object. Retaining referential integrity should be a nightmare. Maybe someone has a nice solution for that.

Comment: Sure - I think that the "Catch" is pretty major in this instance... hmm

Comment: Yep. Can't remember why I didn't put that at the beginning of the post. It's a pretty huge catch. But in principle your problem is interesting. I am working a lot with Enterprise Content Management Systems and they have similar systems in place. The don't "copy" content from their preview systems to their live systems, they "publish" it. But it more or less works the same way.